# Sigevent timer can't be restarted nor it executes a callback

Tags: c++, timer, callback, signals

I have a t_timer set using a struct sigevent and a struct itimerspec of 6 seconds.

My program is supposed to refresh this timer if a certain event happens, otherwise, at timer expiration, the callback should be executed and finally the program should stop

However not only the callback is completely ignored, but I can't restart said timer.

The following is some prelude code, with the variables used in my class. I tried to shorten and simplify the code as much as possible.

```
typedef struct itimerspec TTL;
typedef struct sigevent handler;

struct RtnodeSpvSession : public rtnode::SessionInterface {
   boost::asio::io_service             iSvc;
   timer_t                             tTimer;
   TTL                                 tTimerSetter;
   void OnStart();
   void EnqueueRead();
   void Thread_TTL();
   void ResetTTL;
}

void RtnodeSpvSession::OnStart()
{
   printf("Starting RtnodeSpvSession...\n");
   TTL_Thread();
   iSvc.post(boost::bind(&RtnodeSpvSession::EnqueueRead, this));
}
```

EnqueueRead is called every x seconds and the if statement checks the condition that determines whether or not the reset timer has to take place

```
void RtnodeSpvSession::EnqueueRead()
{
   if (1<2)
   {
      ResetTTL();
   }
   else
   {
      //do nothing
   }
}
```

Callback method for sigevent.At timer expiration this string is never printed nor the method seems to be called at all

```
static void catch_alarm(union sigval sv)
{
   std::cout << "Imma dead\n\n\n\n";
}
```

And finally the timer creation

```
void RtnodeSpvSession::TTL_Thread()
/**
 * Starts the timeout timer
 * When tTimerSetter expires, tTimeoutHandler executes the callback on method catch_alarm
 * and triggers the process kill
 */
{
   handler tTimeoutHandler;
   tTimeoutHandler.sigev_notify = SIGEV_THREAD_ID;            /* Notify via thread */
   tTimeoutHandler.sigev_notify_function = catch_alarm;     /* Thread start function */
   tTimeoutHandler._sigev_un._tid = syscall(SYS_gettid);
   tTimeoutHandler.sigev_signo = SIGHUP;
   tTimeoutHandler.sigev_notify_attributes = NULL;

   if (timer_create(CLOCK_REALTIME, &tTimeoutHandler, &tTimer) == -1) {
      perror("timer_create");
      exit(1);
   }

   memset(&tTimerSetter,0,sizeof(tTimerSetter));
   tTimerSetter.it_value.tv_nsec = 0;
   tTimerSetter.it_value.tv_nsec = 0;
   tTimerSetter.it_value.tv_sec = 6;
   tTimerSetter.it_interval.tv_nsec = 0;
   tTimerSetter.it_interval.tv_sec = 0;
   if (timer_settime(tTimer, 0, &tTimerSetter, NULL) == -1) {
      perror("timer_settime");
      exit(1);
   }
}
```

Here's my clearly flawed reset: I thought deleting and recreating the timer from scratch was the next best option I had, since I wasn't able to directly manipulate the existing timer. But it's useless.

```
void RtnodeSpvSession::ResetTTL()
/// Resets the process's TTL
{
   std::cout << "BEGINNING RESET\n\n\n";
   timer_delete(tTimer);
   TTL_Thread();
}
```

Comment: Since you are using Boost.ASIO, I would suggest you abandon the old C-style `timer_t` and POSIX signals in favor of the much more modern async timers with ASIO. See, e.g., [this example](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tuttimer2.html) from the Boost docs.

Comment: @metal unfortunately I can't. This timer is temporarily being directly implemented in my class but will later be moved inside old legacy code so I'm forced (for now) to use  C-style mechanisms

Comment: Can you show us the code for your signal handler for SIGHUP, as well as anywhere that you call sigaction for it or mask it?

Comment: Even better, show us a [minimal program that demonstrates the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) without all the cruft. It may turn out that in constructing that, you figure out the issue. If not, we'll more easily be able to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found something about this. If you use `SIGEV_THREAD_ID`, the timer will send a signal to the thread id. So you have to install a signal handler in the thread and the function `catch_alarm` won't be called, just the signal handler, but in the thread.

If you use `SIGEV_THREAD`, then the function `catch_alarm` will be called, but you can't set the thread id as it will be created on your behalf.

The following code works as you expect:

```
typedef struct itimerspec TTL;
typedef struct sigevent handler;

void catch_alarm(union sigval sv)
{
    //std::cout << "Imma dead\n\n\n\n";
    printf ("\nSignaled in %d = %d\n\n", syscall(SYS_gettid), sv.sival_int);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        printf ("Process in thread %d\n", i);
        sleep(1);
    }
}

int main ()
{
    timer_t tTimer;
    TTL tTimerSetter;
    handler tTimeoutHandler;

    printf ("My pid: %d %d\n", getpid(), syscall(SYS_gettid));
    
    memset(&tTimeoutHandler,0,sizeof(tTimeoutHandler));
    tTimeoutHandler.sigev_notify = SIGEV_THREAD;            /* Notify via thread */
    tTimeoutHandler.sigev_notify_function = catch_alarm;     /* Thread start function */
    tTimeoutHandler.sigev_value.sival_int = 9999;
    tTimeoutHandler.sigev_notify_attributes = NULL;

    printf ("Creating timer\n");
    if (timer_create(CLOCK_REALTIME, &tTimeoutHandler, &tTimer) == -1) {
        perror("timer_create");
        exit(1);
    }

    memset(&tTimerSetter,0,sizeof(tTimerSetter));
    tTimerSetter.it_value.tv_nsec = 0;
    tTimerSetter.it_value.tv_nsec = 0;
    tTimerSetter.it_value.tv_sec = 5;
    tTimerSetter.it_interval.tv_nsec = 0;
    tTimerSetter.it_interval.tv_sec = 0;
    if (timer_settime(tTimer, 0, &tTimerSetter, NULL) == -1) {
        perror("timer_settime");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf ("To wait\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        printf ("Waiting %d\n", i);
        sleep(1);
    }

    printf ("Finished\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Ouput:

```
My pid: 27473 27473
Creating timer
To wait
Waiting 0
Waiting 1
Waiting 2
Waiting 3
Waiting 4

Signaled in 27477 = 9999

Process in thread 0
Waiting 5
Process in thread 1
Waiting 6
Process in thread 2
Waiting 7
Process in thread 3
Waiting 8
Process in thread 4
Waiting 9
Waiting 10
Waiting 11
Waiting 12
Waiting 13
Waiting 14
Finished
```

> SIGEV_THREAD_ID (Linux-specific)
> As for SIGEV_SIGNAL, but the signal is targeted at the thread whose ID is given in sigev_notify_thread_id

The key: *As for SIGEV_SIGNAL*.

As said, if you use `SIGEV_THREAD_ID` you must create the thread and *a signal* will be sent to that thread.